# New Relic: Can alert be created for custom metrics?

Tags: newrelic

New Relic gives support for server monitoring alerts out of the box for the followings:
    CPU busy
    Disk busy
    Memory used
    Disk space used

Can we also add alert for other types of metrics (like custom metrics)?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For web transactions that are not custom metrics, you can make them into Key Transactions and set alerts and alert thresholds for those Key Transactions individually. See https://newrelic.com/docs/transactions-dashboards/key-transactions.

At this time, however, custom metrics cannot be made into Key Transactions. You can view them on custom dashboards, but to be alerted about them you will need to write a plugin.
You can get started by reading this article: https://newrelic.com/docs/plugin-dev/working-directly-with-the-plugin-api

You could also write to New Relic support to make a feature request, asking for alerting on custom metrics.

Comment: Thanks for information. As a follow up question. I also have this use case: I want to be alerted by New Relic server if my New Relic agent is not reporting any data (from my host to New Relic site), say, for 30 mins.

Is it possible to do with the New Relic agent running in my app server ?

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: They have a new system in beta that would allow this, but not all users have access to it. If you have just made a new account then it won't be available to you yet.